# powerapps set default value on a lookup field of Sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint, lookup, powerapps

hallo i have powerapps edit form of a sharePoint listA that contain a lookUp filed.
the lookUp filed contain ids from listB.

i need the value of this lookUp filed to be selected automatically.

[image: this is the lookup filed in the powerApps form]

[image]

I tried to First(filter()) the Choice collection but no success.. any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PowerApps LookUp() function can contain two or three arguments and needs somekind of matching criteria.

`LookUp(dataSource, column = value)` returns the first record that matches the criteria

`LookUp(dataSource, column1 = value, column2)` returns a single column (`column2`) in the first record that matches the criteria.

You likely don't need the Sharepoint "Lookup-type" column once you get the hang of the PowerApps LookUp() function. (in fact, with Sharepoint as a data source, I NEVER use complex column types except for people-type).

Comment: thank you ... i put your LookUp suggest in the defaultSelectedItems and its works!!